# How to switch between two functions?

Tags: javascript, html, countdowntimer

```
var k = 0,
  m = 0,
  s = 59,
  c = 1;
//var session=false;
var arr;
var tick;

function breaktime() {
  clearInterval(tick);
  k = parseInt(document.getElementById('bk2').innerHTML);
  m = k;
  s = 59;
  if (c < 0)
    c = 1;
  c--;
  if (c >= 0) {
    tick = setInterval(function() {
      if (m >= 0) { //k--;
        //m=k;

        if (s >= 10 && m >= 0) {

          document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = m + ":" + s;
          s--;

        } else if (s >= 0 && m >= 0) {

          document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = m + ":" + "0" + s;
          s--;
        } else //if(s<=0)
        {
          m--;
          s = 59;
        }
        //else

        //document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML=m+":"+"0"+s;
      } else {
        document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = "00:00";
        clock();
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
}
document.onclick =
  function clock() {
    clearInterval(tick);
    k = (document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML).toString();
    arr = k.split(":");
    m = parseInt(arr[0]);
    s = parseInt(arr[1]);
    if (s >= 10)
      document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = m + ":" + s;
    else
      document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = m + ":" + "0" + s;
    if (c < 0)
      c = 1;
    c--;
    if (c >= 0) {
      tick = setInterval(function() {
        if (m >= 0) { //k--;
          //m=k;

          if (s >= 10 && m >= 0) {

            document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = m + ":" + s;
            s--;

          } else if (s >= 0 && m >= 0) {

            document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = m + ":" + "0" + s;
            s--;
          } else //if(s<=0)
          {
            m--;
            s = 59;
          }
          //else

          //document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML=m+":"+"0"+s;
        } else {
          document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = "00:00";
          breaktime();
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  };
```

I want the first the countdown timer to count from minutes predecided in "clock" div element and then after it becomes zero then the breaktime countdown timer begins which take predecide value stored in "bk2" div element.

The problem I am facing is that my countdown timer stops after "clock" becomes "00:00" ,I want it to restart from value in "bk2",but I am unable to switch between breaktime function and clock function.

Comment: Have a look at *named anonymous functions* . Your clock function is one.

Comment: can you make jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.onclick=
function clock(){ 
    console.log(clock);//works
    console.log(document.onclick);//works
};
console.log(clock);//WORKS NOT
console.log(document.onclick);//works
```

Your clock function is an *named anonymous function* . Its made to make recursion possible in anonymous functions. To access it outside, you must use

```
document.onclick();
```

but thats quite bad style. Or you do:

```
clock = document.onclick=function(){}
```

Wich will define clock outside of the function, making

```
clock();
```

possible....

Comment: I am unable to call breaktime() inside setInterval of clock()